# Authentication error with pygsheets used from Jupyter notebook

Tags: pygsheets

I am trying to use `pyghsheets` from within a Jupyter notebook and I do not get it to work, while the same piece of code works nicely from within `ipython`.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pygsheets

creds = Path(r"/path/to/client_secret.json")

gc = pygsheets.authorize(client_secret=creds)

book = gc.open_by_key("__key__of__sheet__")
wks = book.worksheet_by_title("Sheet1")
wks.clear(start="A2")
```

When called from within ipython everthing works fine, whereas from within a Jupyter notebook I get

```
RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

I run both pieces from within the same conda environment. Any suggestion on how to narrow down the problem (and solutions) are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that current working directory of my Jupyter notebook was not the same as the one of my plain ipython. Now `pygsheets` stores the token that is used for authentication with Google in the current working directory. If the `.json` file in that directory is invalid, authentication will fail.

You can add a parameter `credentials_directory=...` to specify a previously validated token file.

The solution I ended up with was

```py
gc = pygsheets.authorize(client_secret=creds, credentials_directory=creds.parent)
```

That way token and credential files are in the same directory.